# How can i use intValue() in Generic Class

Tags: java, string, generics, integer, int

I am certainly facing a problem with a task i have at university:

```
public class Num<Integer> { 
    Integer x;
    Integer y;

    public Num(Integer x, Integer y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }

 // now i have to write a method whitch returns (x, y) as a String
    public String intValue() {

    }
```

I have no idea if i have the correct basic approach or how this will work. 
I wanted to write in the method intValue:

int i = x.IntValue();

int j = y.IntValue();

return "(" i "," j ")";

EDIT: I solved the problem. May someone confirm whether it is correct:

```
public class Zahl<T> {
public Integer x;
public Integer y;

public Zahl(Integer x, Integer y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}   

 public String intValue() {
   int i = this.x.intValue();
   int j = this.y.intValue();
   return "(" + i + "," + j + ")";
} 
}
```

EDIT 2: Problem solved! Thanks for helping out that fast :-)

Here is the correct code:

```
class Zahl<N extends Number> {
N x;
N y;

Zahl(N x, N y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
 String intValue() {
   return "(" + x.intValue() + "," + y.intValue() + ")";
} 

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zahl<Integer> z = new Zahl<>(7, 8);
    System.out.println(z.intValue());
   }
}
```

Output: (7,8)

Comment: Using `Integer` for the name of the type parameter is a very bad idea... Call it `N` or `T` but not `Integer`...

Comment: Try `return "(" + i + ", " + j + ")";`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `<Integer>` on the first line? Do you really want to involve generics? If so, what outcome are you looking for?

Comment: @slim 
That was a mistake of mine. Originally I wanted to set the generic Type to <T> :-) Sorry

Comment: Having a method named `intValue()` return a `String` seems very, very wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Integer for the name of the type parameter is a very bad idea... Call it N or T but not Integer...

```
public class Num<N> {
  ...
}
```

Now the only thing we know about `N` is that it's an `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have an `intValue` method. So you probably want to make sure that `N` is a `Number`:

```
public class Num<N extends Number> {
  ...
}
```

Now you can write your class:

```
public class Num<N extends Number> { 
  N x;
  N y;

  public Num(N x, N y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }

  public String intValue() {
    return "(" + x.intValue() + ", " + y.intValue() + ")";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the fields and return that e.g.

```
 public String intValue() {
       return (x + " " + y);
    }
```